# Zooming on Leaflet map within iframe causes Samsung Galaxy to freeze map

Tags: leaflet, javascript

**Situation**

We need our map to capture pointer events to interact with 6.000+ canvas shapes, plotted on a GridLayer. We need to check for click events, mouse moves, etc. on the canvases.
All works fine when the map is not loaded within an iframe.

To capture pointer events, we have set:

```
.leaflet-tile-container{ pointer-events:visiblePainted; pointer-events:auto }
```

However, when the map is displayed within an iframe (with pointer-events set to auto) Samsung Galaxy devices cause the map to freeze after zooming in / out after a while (fast zooming causes the map to freeze quickly)

On all other touch devices, except for Samsung devices, the map works just fine (also within an iframe). We have tested multiple Android and iOS devices (HTC One, OnePlus, iPhone 5, iPhone7 etc.)

**Steps to reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Step 1: Test on a Samsung Galaxy

Step 2: Open https://onlinebikelight.com/galaxy.html

Step 3: Start zooming in / out fast

... Map freezes

**Expected behavior**

Expected behavior: Map shouldn't freeze.

When the map is not loaded in an iframe but directly in the browser, like here:

https://onlinebikelight.com/map.html

, the map won't freeze on a Samsung Galaxy.

**Current behavior**

The map freezes when loaded within an iframe on a Samsung Galaxy, with pointer-events set to auto.

**Environment**

- Leaflet 1.4.0
- Browser: Chrome (all recent versions)
- OS: Android (all recent versions)
- Devices: Samsung Galaxy (tested on Galaxy S6, S8,    S9)

**Minimal example reproducing the issue**

*IMPORTANT: Test on Samsung Galaxy!*

Works perfectly fine when zooming in / out in browser: 
https://onlinebikelight.com/map.html

However, map freezes when embedded in iframe:
https://onlinebikelight.com/galaxy.html

**Update:**

The map freeze within an iframe doesn't seem to occur on a Samsung Galaxy when opened in Firefox..

Comment: Did you try Firefox? And by the way, page https://onlinebikelight.com/galaxy.html requires password.

Comment: Yes we did, the issue doesn't seem to occur in Firefox.. I will add it to the question.
Oh, I'm sorry, I included the wrong src in the iframe.
A password isn't required anymore.

Comment: One possibility would be that Leaflet does not detect correctly the OS and browser environment. Check what you get for `L.Browser.android`, `L.Browser.androidStock` and `L.Browser.chrome` in environments where it works and on Galaxy.